# Creating command button and writing code programmatically in a userform module

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I'm trying to do:

1 Check the number of versions of a file in a folder,

2 Add as many buttons in a userform as the number of versions,

3 Write code for each button to, for example, show a MsgBox

With the code below, number of versions is checked correctly, buttons are created correctly too and the code is added in the userform module correctly, but ... when I click on any of the buttons (created for each version), nothing happens. Help!!!

```
Dim Boton As MSForms.CommandButton
Dim Fichero_Secundaria_Hoy As String
Dim Versiones_secundaria(8) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Number_of_versions As Integer
Dim Code As String
Dim j As Integer

Fichero_Secundaria_Hoy = Dir("C:\Prueba\pdvd_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "*")

Do While Fichero_Secundaria_Hoy <> ""
    Versiones_secundaria(i) = Mid(Fichero_Secundaria_Hoy, 27, 1)
    Fichero_Secundaria_Hoy = Dir
    i = i + 1
Loop

Number_of_versions = i
Version_secundaria.Height = 18 + 24 * Number_of_versions

With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Version_secundaria").CodeModule
    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
End With

For i = 0 To  Number_of_versions - 1
    Set Boton = Version_secundaria.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1", "Version" & Versiones_secundaria(i))
    Version_secundaria.Controls("version" & Versiones_secundaria(i)).Caption = Versiones_secundaria(i)

    Code = "Sub " & Boton.Name & "_Click()" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "Call Mostrar_secundaria" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "Version_secundaria.Hide" & vbCrLf
    Code = Code & "End Sub"

    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Version_secundaria").CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, Codigo_del_boton
    End With

Next i
```

This code is in a normal module, and the code written programmatically appears in the existing userform module called "Version_secundaria".

Seems that clicking the button doesn't take to the Sub Button_click, but don't know why!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe what you want is possible.  There was a similar question a year or two ago.  The OP’s objective was very different from yours but also required the creation of source code at runtime.  My recollection is that the OP was told that it not possible to create and execute source code in the same run.  I cannot find anything on the web to confirm or deny this limitation.  I also recall an alternative approach to the requirement was posted.  It might have been me since I remember considering how to achieve the required effect.

You might also like to consider this warning from C Pearson:

> CAUTION: Many VBA-based computer viruses propagate themselves by
>   creating and/or modifying VBA code. Therefore, many virus scanners may
>   automatically and without warning or confirmation delete modules that
>   reference the VBProject object, causing a permanent and irretrievable
>   loss of code. Consult the documentation for your anti-virus software
>   for details.

The code below offers an alternative approach to achieving the effect I believe you seek.

I have created a user form and have populated it with 20 option buttons, 1 command button and 1 label.  I have left the form and the controls with default names except for the command button which I renamed cmdExit.  I placed the Exit button and the label where I wished them to be.  The option buttons were placed at random and made invisible (property Visible = False).  This may not be enough option buttons for your needs but you can have many, many more controls before the form slows down noticeably.

I created a small routine to display the form:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DsplForm()

  Load UserForm1
  UserForm1.Show vbModal

End Sub
```

The basis of the code within the form is the collection `Controls` which contains all the controls on the form.  You can access the properties of a control via its name or via the Controls collection.  For example, if control 5 is Label1 then the following are equivalent:

```
Label1.Caption = "xxxx"
Controls(5).Caption = "xxxx"
```

This allows runtime access to similar controls without having specific code for each control.

I use the form’s initialise routine to get everything ready:

1. Scan `Controls` for option buttons and count them.
2. Size array OptButCtrl according to the number of buttons.
3. Record the control number for each button in array OptButCtrl.  I do not care about the sequence.  It is difficult to get `OptionButton2` before `OptionButton1` in `Controls` but it would not matter if you did.
4. I initialise array OptButDesc().  This is the array that determines how many option buttons are displayed.  You would need to size this array according to the number of versions and to load this array with the names and details of the versions.
5. The appropriate number of option buttons are displayed in a list.

The click routines for all the option buttons call a single routine which sets all option buttons, other than the selected one, to Off/False.  Label1 is set to the description of the selected button.

Come back with questions as necessary but I believe I have given you enough information to show how to achieve the effect you seek.

```
Option Explicit
  Dim OptButCtrl() As Long
  Dim OptButDesc() As String
Private Sub cmdExit_Click()

  Unload Me

End Sub
' VB.Net has the functionality to allow one routine handle the events for
' several controls.  I can find no equivalent functonality with VBA. This
' approach is the best I have found.
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(1)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(2)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(3)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(4)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton5_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(5)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton6_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(6)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton7_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(7)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton8_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(8)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton9_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(9)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton10_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(10)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton11_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(11)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton12_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(12)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton13_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(13)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton14_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(14)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton15_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(15)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton16_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(16)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton17_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(17)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton18_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(18)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton19_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(19)
End Sub
Private Sub OptionButton20_Click()
  Call OptionButtonAny(20)
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim InxCtrl As Long
  Dim InxOptBut As Long
  Dim Left As Long
  Dim NumOptButs As Long
  Dim Top As Long

  ' Scan all controls and count those that are Option buttons
  NumOptButs = 0
  For InxCtrl = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
    With Controls(InxCtrl)
      If Mid(.Name, 1, 12) = "OptionButton" Then
        NumOptButs = NumOptButs + 1
      End If
    End With
  Next

  ' Size array according to number of option buttons found
  ReDim OptButCtrl(0 To NumOptButs - 1)

  ' Record control numbers of option buttons in array OptButCtrl()
  InxOptBut = LBound(OptButCtrl)
  For InxCtrl = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
    With Controls(InxCtrl)
      If Mid(.Name, 1, 12) = "OptionButton" Then
        OptButCtrl(InxOptBut) = InxCtrl
        InxOptBut = InxOptBut + 1
      End If
    End With
  Next

  ' The lower bound of OptButCtrl and OptButDesc must be the same.
  ' The size of this array controls how many option buttons are displayed.
  ReDim OptButDesc(0 To 5)

  OptButDesc(0) = "Desc for Button 1"
  OptButDesc(1) = "Desc for Button 2"
  OptButDesc(2) = "Desc for Button 3"
  OptButDesc(3) = "Desc for Button 4"
  OptButDesc(4) = "Desc for Button 5"
  OptButDesc(5) = "Desc for Button 6"

  ' These control the top left corner of the first option button
  Left = 5
  Top = 5

  ' Display one button for each description in OptButDesc()
  For InxOptBut = LBound(OptButCtrl) To UBound(OptButCtrl)
    InxCtrl = OptButCtrl(InxOptBut)
    If InxOptBut <= UBound(OptButDesc) Then
      ' This button is required
      With Controls(InxCtrl)
        .Top = Top
        Top = Top + .Height + 5
        .Left = Left
        .Visible = True
        .Caption = OptButDesc(InxOptBut)
      End With
    Else
      ' This button is not required
      Controls(InxCtrl).Visible = False
    End If
  Next

End Sub
Sub OptionButtonAny(ByVal OptButNum As Long)

  Dim InxCtrl As Long
  Dim InxOptBut As Long

  ' Find Control for selected Option button.
  ' Set all other option buttons to Off.
  ' Display description of selected button in Label1
  For InxOptBut = LBound(OptButCtrl) To UBound(OptButCtrl)
    InxCtrl = OptButCtrl(InxOptBut)
    With Controls(InxCtrl)
      If .Name = "OptionButton" & OptButNum Then
        Label1.Caption = OptButDesc(InxOptBut)
      Else
        .Value = False
      End If
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

I should add that I am not convinced this is the best way to handle your requirement.  I believe I would load all the versions to a ListBox and let the use select the required row.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I suppose you are right, it makes sense. I have to read carefully your answer. The solution I have found is to create many buttons, put them in one column, and adjust the height of the userform, so the user  can only see the working buttons .